# Перебор пикселей в Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

Есть программка WinForms, где пользователь вводит цифру, которая означает сколько пикселей изменить в изображение. Есть три переменных: firstKey и secondKey, bias - для смещения, первые две вводятся пользователем, третьей изначально присваивается значение secondKey. В выбранные пиксели делаю градацию серого цвета. Делаю так:

```
for (x = 0; x < c * firstKey; x += firstKey)
{
    for (y = bias; y < bias + 1; y++)
    {
        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(greyGrad[grayValue], greyGrad[grayValue], greyGrad[grayValue]);
        image1.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
    }
    grayValue++;
    bias += secondKey;
}
pictureBox1.Image = image1;
```

Переменная С - количество пикселей, которых нужно изменить.
Если делать таким образом, то перебор пикселей происходит по диагонали с левого верхнего угла до нижнего правого. Вопрос состоим в том, как можно реализовать, чтоб пиксели не по диагонали менялись, а в разных местах изображения? Рандом не подходит, так как в другой программке я должен получить эти значения, если ввести firstKey и secondKey. Изображение не искажается, не сжимается, деформации не подлежит, так как всё работает, если менять таким образом как я. Можно вообще обойтись без ключей, чисто от количества пикселей, которых нужно поменять. Я пробовал ещё так: высоту изображения делил на количество пикселей, получал в каких рядах менять пиксели, а "x" я уже делал рандомно в диапазоне от нуля до ширины изображения. Но при таком подходе, желая получить значение во второй проге, цикл просто зависал, очень долго перебирал все пиксели и в итоге результата не давал всё равно.

Comment: Можете по-простому, что нужно было сделать то? Нарисовать градиент? Горизонтальный, вертикальный диагональный? Добавьте `grayValue = 0` перед `for (y = bias`.

Comment: А еще, `GetPixel` и `SetPixel` если вам нужно быстро обрабатывать изображения, вам не подходят.

Comment: _получить значение во второй проге_ - [Стеганографию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стеганография) пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @aepot  пользователь вводит сколько пикселей поменять и два ключа (шаги), которые определяют координаты пикселей, которые меняются. Во второй программе я должен получить эти значения цвета, которые я закладывал в первой программе, введя те же ключи. У меня это как бы по диагонали меняются, а мне нужно в разных местах изображения. Можно реализовать вообще без ключей, все равно. Лишь бы работало и пиксели менялись в разных местах изображения.

Comment: @Alexandr Petrov Александр, что-то вроде того.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov и я это делаю, только проблема состоит в том, что пиксели красятся по диагонали, слишком видно.

Comment: @ЯрославОвчар  `что-то вроде того` ведь можно было это сразу в вопросе описать? Тогда было бы понятно, о чём вы вообще. Что за ключ, что за еще ключ, как это работает и как должно - не понятно. При обращении к пользователю его никнейм после собачки пишите без пробела.

Comment: @aepot ключи - это просто смещение. Вот координаты первого пикселя 0.0, если ключи допустим будут 3 и 2, тогда координаты второго будет 3.2, третьего 6.4

Comment: `Вопрос состоим в том` если картинку сохранить в жпег например как сжатие с потерями, то значения в измененных пикселях изменятся. Поэтому шифрование информации в виде единичных пикселей при наличии сжатия с потерями не сработает. Ну или я не понял задачу. Не будете же вы многомегабайтные битмапы передавать?

Comment: @aepot У меня все работает. Я уже все сделал, изображение в формате tiff сохраняется, сжатия не происходит и потерь никаких тоже нет. Суть вопроса просто в том, как можно пиксели эти не тупо по диагонали выбирать.

Comment: ну `линейный индекс пикселя = ширина * y + x`, в обратную сторону тоже легко конвертируется. Если сжатие гарантированно без потерь, можете еще на содержимое изображения ориентироваться. Например, если красного в пикселе больше 128, то отступить 2 пикселя, иначе один. С этой идеей можно поиграться в разные стороны.